# Git silently reverted commit without explanation

Tags: git

A developer asked where his fix to a TR had gone. After examining the branch, it was indeed not there.
I assumed he had just forgotten to forward merge the fix, as is fairly common. After looking, the fix had indeed been committed with commit 'A', committed at a point 2 in the timeline.

In parallel, another branch was working on another TR. This branch was branched before 'A' was committed, and thus it was not included.

After a while, this parallel branch was merged into the main branch with commit 'B' (merge commit). Similar to:

```
O
| \
A  |
| /
B
```

Despite not having touched the same files as 'A', the merge silently reverted the changes in 'A' without conflict, in fact, running

```
git blame
```

after the merge shows 'A' never happened.

However, running

```
git --contains
```

shows us that 'A' definitely happened. So the changes were all silently reverted, without a commit.

After attempting the merge between the same two parents, all changes in 'A' are indeed overridden.
Furthermore, the original merge was done via a PR on ADS, so there is no chance of any crazy flags being used in the final merge. The PR shows indeed that the files *will* be changed, which was overlooked on the developers' part.

What could have caused Git to get the merge so wrong? Something earlier in the history? (Remember, the files in 'A' had not been touched by any commit that made up the second parent in 'B').

Comment: If you run `git merge-base --all <merge parent 1> <merge parent 2>`, does it return single hash or several?

Answer (score 1):

(Note: this is not a complete answer, and as such, might deserve to be a comment—but I need formatting and lots of space...)

> Despite not having touched the same files as 'A', the merge silently reverted the changes in 'A' without conflict ...

This is ... hard to believe—this sort of thing is usually user-error—but:

> After attempting the merge between the same two parents, all changes in 'A' are indeed overridden

*this* suggests that it indeed is happening.

The most obvious candidate that would allow for this is that there are differences in both `A` and some other commit after `O` but before `B`, *and* there is a `.gitattributes` that defines a *merge driver* for these files.  This merge driver is in charge of doing actual merge work, and if it does that work by ignoring the copy of the file in `A` in favor of the copy in the other commit.

As [max630 suggests in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64609393/git-silently-reverted-commit-without-explanation#comment114252630_64609393), it may also be a good idea to check whether `O` is a simple, single merge base, or whether Git is computing a synthetic commit to use as a merge base via the `recursive` strategy.

That is, given:

```
O---A---M
 \     /
  X---Y
```

then `git merge-base --all A Y` will produce the hash ID of commit `O`, but in more complex cases, there might be multiple merge bases.  The `-s recursive` (default) merge strategy will first merge the merge bases, then use the resulting temporary commit<sup>1</sup> as the merge base for `A` and `Y`.  If you find that there are two or more merge base commits, you can merge them yourself to see what the resulting temporary commit was (see also footnote 1) and use that to figure out what happened.

If there is only a single merge base, then a merge driver that used the files from `Y`, for some reason, would explain the result in commit `M`.  But the merge driver defined in `.gitattributes` is run only if all three copies of the files (in `O`, `A`, and `Y`) differ, so if the copies on `O` and `Y` match, Git should have taken the copies from `A`.

Other than that, if some other merge strategy were used, *that* could explain the result, but when you re-do the merge, you supply a new merge strategy every time.<sup>2</sup>  So I think that rules out this possibility.

---

<sup>1</sup>The recursive strategy really does make temporary commits for each of these intermediate merge bases, but it does not leave you any good way to *find* the hash IDs of these temporary commits.  They're not in any ref name or any reflog.  The `git gc` code will delete them once they're past loose-object-expiry time.

<sup>2</sup>If you don't supply `-s strategy`, Git picks one: `recursive` by default for a two-commit merge, `octopus` by default for a 3-or-more-commit merge.

Comment: `git show M` returns the Y and O as the parents.

`git merge-base --all A Y` returns a single hash (O).

A correctly contains the changes. These files _have not been touched_ in any of the commits from the branch. M does not contain them. They do however show up as changes that will be applied, but there is no commit related to this, essentially revert. It is incredibly weird. I'm not really sure where to go from here to understand what happened since everything seems normal. There will probably be a tool to verify all changes are tied to a commit in a merge, for the future, but for now...

Comment: `Y` and `O`?  There is no `A`? Or was that a typo, the parents are Y and A and the base is O?

Comment: Sorry, `Y` and `A` are the parents. `git merge-base --all A Y` returns a single hash, in fact, it returns `A` as the single merge-base. Which may not be wrong in this case? I'm not sure about anything related to this case anymore. :)

Comment: Interesting: if the merge base is one of the inputs, `git merge` normally just does a fast-forward. So someone had to force the merge (or one of the commits is tagged; merging a tagged commit is a special case; or the merge was done on GitHub, which forces a merge; etc.). But re-merging it manually with `--no-ff` should produce the correct merge.

Comment: One of the parents (Y) is indeed a tag.

The merge was done on ADS via a PR.

Comment: I have no idea what "ADS" is, but given the way Git works, that would explain why `git merge` would do a real merge when a fast-forward was otherwise possible. (As noted, there are other possible reasons for that, but this one suffices.) I now wonder if ADS has affected the merge result in some way, though.

Comment: Azure DevOps Server.
I also thought ADS was responsible, but merging locally using the terminal gave me the same result. I feel like a force-push was involved, but the developers swear they didn't, I'm just stumped how the history could be unrecordedly reverted otherwise. The tag was, by the way, created from the commit. The merge was done on the commits, not on the tag by name, if that matters. I'm leaning more and more towards it being a developer error and not wanting to admit, rather than some weird behavior, because nothing weird has really been done, or at least recorded, in the branch.